# Can I Render IMGUI on Display 2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, imgui

I wanna Draw Texture using GUI
and I set Camera Target Display to Display 2

But DrawTexture draw it on Display 1 only

I wonder How Can I Draw GUI on Display 2?

```
private void OnGUI()
{
    Vector3 pos = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(position); 
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(1,1);
    Matrix4X4 matrixBackup = GUI.matrix;
    GUI.color = Color.red;

    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(pos.x, pos.y, length, width), tex);
    GUI.matrix = matrixBackup;
}
```

Comment: You could try an instead go through [`OnRenderImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderImage.html)